# Printing phone number of the user using senchaTouch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need to know if there's anyway i could get the users mobile number using `SenchaTouch`. I am really new to this framework, and can someone help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly hope not! Sencha is a server side framework for building web applications.

What you ask for would be a huge privacy invasion. A web site could harvest phone numbers from all visiting mobile users...

Comment: Then, can we get the UDID of the user ?

Comment: No, for the same reason we you can't get the phone number :)

Comment: So, the theory here is that a web page cann't render any device information. Thank you for helping me out. I am new to Sencha :)

Answer (score 1):

That is certainly not possible....and sencha touch is just a mobile java script framework.
This library definitely has no such capability to do so. Definitely a crime hacking to hack phone number who will browse the website or app.

Comment: If so, Will there be a possibility to obtain the UDID of the user ?

Comment: Udid of wat... The device can have a udid, Facebook udid used and if an iOS os, udid of apple??? I hope ths can be cracked, yet not sure